# How to make a shortcut with Wix v4 Heat Harvesting?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, heat, wix4

I am trying to create a shortcut from an exe to the `StartMenuFolder` and `DesktopFolder` using Wix v4 for a Heat Harvested application.

Using this, my desired behavior is that I can add a `Shortcut` to an exe from the `HarvestedComponents` gathered by the `HarvestGroup` denoted below from my .wixproj file in both the `DesktopFolder` and `StartMenuFolder`.

```
<HarvestDirectory Include="../harvestDirectory/">
  <ComponentGroupName>HarvestedComponents</ComponentGroupName>
  <DirectoryRefId>INSTALLFOLDER</DirectoryRefId>
  <SuppressRootDirectory>true</SuppressRootDirectory>
</HarvestDirectory>
```

In the `Package.wxs`, I tried to create a Component containing a Shortcut referencing the INSTALLFOLDER, however giving it a Target and `Advertise='yes'` result in an error saying that the Target and Advertise cannot be specified together. I would understand this behavior if I were able to set the file of the Shortcut beforehand, as seen in the [streams from Rob Mensching](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7MQCF5AZcw) going over Wix v4.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:ui="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui">
    <Package Name="App 1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Manufacturer" Version="1.0.0.0"
             UpgradeCode="{Guid}">
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeError)" />

        <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="Include/License.rtf" />
        <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="Include/banner.bmp" />
        <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="Include/image.bmp" />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

        <ui:WixUI Id="WixUI_InstallDir" InstallDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />

        <Feature Id="Main">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="HarvestedComponents" />
            <ComponentRef Id="ShortcutsSetup" />
        </Feature>

        <Component Id="ShortcutsSetup" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Guid="{Guid}">
            <Shortcut Id="StartMenuShortcut" Directory="StartMenuFolder" Target="App.exe"
                      Name="App 1.0.0.0" Advertise="yes" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"/>
        </Component>
    </Package>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `Target` attribute is for a non-advertised Shortcut according to the documentation [here](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/schema/wxs/shortcut/), so you can't use `Target` and `Advertise="yes"` together. If you want to use [Advertisement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/advertisement), choose `Advertise=yes` and drop the `Target`. Otherwise, do the opposite.

Comment: By using the HarvestComponents as mentioned in the question, if I use Target and remove Advertise I get the following: `ICE57: Component 'ShortcutsSetup' has both per-user and per-machine data with a per-machine KeyPath.` Specifically with the Harvesting, there seems to not be a way to declare a Shortcut to the exe.

Comment: I believe I worked around this by creating a registry key that points to the HKCU hive (which is per-user) and setting that as the keypath. I am fairly new to using WiXtoolset as well so I don't quite understand why this is even necessary, but it got me working.

Comment: EDIT:  Doesn't look like multiline works in here. To make it less confusing, add something like:  `<RegistryValue Id="RegMenuShortcut" Root="HKCU" Key="Software\MyCompany\MyShortcut" Name="MenuSC" Value="1" Type="integer" KeyPath="yes" />` into the shortcut component (along with the shortcut element).